# Why is a=4 evaluated as true but b=0 evaluated as false in an if condition?

Tags: c

Why is the first condition a=4 considered as true and b=0 is treated as false in the below if condition ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a,b;
  if(a=4)
    printf("a=4 --> true");
  else
    printf("a=4 --> false");

  if(b=0)
    printf("\nb=0 --> true");
  else
    printf("\nb=0 --> false");

  printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
a=4 --> true  
b=0 --> false
```

Comment: Did you actually want an equality comparison: `if(a==4)`? You are aware that what you have is simply an assignment?

Comment: You might want to [review this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm) before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment expression

```
x = n
```

evaluates to the value assigned to `x`. So `a = 4` evaluates to `4`, and `b = 0` evaluates to `0`. In C and C++, non-zero values are true, and zero values are false.

Comment: OK, what is wrong with this answer? Two down-votes suggests there might be a problem, but I can't see it.

Comment: It exists. That's the problem!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, that's fine then. I don't see it as a problem. I assume not everybody knows what an assignment expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 5):

In both C and C++ language, any non-zero value is treated as `true`. In `if` condition you are assigning `4` and `0` to `a` and `b` causing the value of expressions `a = 4` and `b = 0` to be `4` and `0` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Because what you are testing is NOT if b is equal to 0 or not. If you want to check that you should write:

```
b=0; // assign the value

if(b==0) { // check if b is 0
}
```

What you are doing is assigning 0 to b then condition is true is b is not true. In other words what your are doing is similar to:

```
b=0;
if(b) {
}
```

of course this if condition will not enter since b is 0, which is the same as False.

Answer (score 0):

To compare values, use `==`. `=` is an assignment operator that returns the value you assigned. And then every integer value not equal to `0` is treated as a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression
>   compares unequal to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is
>   executed if the expression compares equal to 0.

Thus in this code snippet

```
  if(a=4)
    printf("a=4 --> true");
  else
    printf("a=4 --> false");
```

expression `a = 4` is not equal to 0. So the first substatement of the if is executed.

In this code snippet

```
  if(b=0)
    printf("\nb=0 --> true");
  else
    printf("\nb=0 --> false");
```

expression `b = 0` is equal to 0. So the second substatement of the if (that is that corresponds to else)  is executed.